# Some glyphs won't copy from Illustrator into InDesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, fonts, glyphs

I'm trying to copy a table created in Illustrator (not in the screenshot) into InDesign but glyphs like currency symbol or other mutations won't copy properly.

Illustrator on the left and InDesign on the right:

[image: Illustrator on the left and InDesign on the right.]

It would be nice if I could copy the whole Table, which I created in Illustrator and still be able to edit it in InDesign.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of table you have in AI, but it does look like you are using different fonts between AI and ID. The font used in ID might not have the same character set as the one used in AI. If you would use the same font, the characters should work.

Comment: I didn't change the font, just copied it from IL to ID. It also looks like ID ist creating outlines, and the text can't be edited.

Comment: @daniel  I don't know about the glyphs issue. About the outlining issue, you should understand that INDD outlines text in order to keep appearance.  So, instead of directly copying/pasting your text, paste it into a text frame. Of course, you'll have to recreate a paragraph style in INDD to match your AI style.